# multiple image stitching

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have successfully implemented an algorithm to calculate a transformation that aligns feature matching using RANSAC. After that I can stitch the images. But now I am trying to do this for multiple images. 
I can compute the transformation for each pair of images and stitch them together. But i want on a whole. Is it possible?

Comment: While I don't know if it is possible using a RANSAC approach, I do know it is possible in general. [AutoStitch](http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/brown/autostitch/autostitch.html) does this, but I don't think they have published the underlying approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to map all images into one place defined by a specific 'destination image'.

I.e., pick a certain image (Should probably be in the middle of the pack in terms of where the camera points) and compute the transformation between that destination image and every other image.

Then map every image into the destination space.

I guess you could also map all images into some *other* destination space/projection -- but you need something more than RANSAC for this.

Comment: I am trying to implement the algorithm written by Lowe. I could do image matching for 2 images. But the next step is finding the connected components between images and applying bundle adjustment for each connected component. For 2 images after applying RANSAC i know the connected components and can stitch it, but when it is multiple images I cant follow what to do